# Shortlist and reject button not working properly

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

Whenever I click on buttons only the last one is working rest on the table buttons are not working

Here is my html File

```
`<div class="body table-responsive">
    <form id="form" method="POST" action = "#">
                {% csrf_token %}
        <table class="table table-hover" id="customers">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width: 1%;" >S No.</th>
                    <th style="width: 10%;" >Name</th>
                    <th style="width: 5%;" >Experience</th>
                    <th style="width: 5%;" >Main Skills</th>
                    <th style="width: 10%;" ><center>#</center></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                    {% for Application in Job.applications.all %}
                <tr>

                    <th scope="row"> {{ forloop.counter }}</th>
                    <td><a style="font-size: medium;"  href="{% url 'application' Application.id            %}">{{Application.created_by.username}}</a></td>
                    <td>{{Application.Experience}}</td>
                    <td>{{Application.Skills}}</td>
                    <td><center>
                        <input type="submit" value="Shortlist" name="status" >
                        <input type="hidden" name="Application_id" value= "{{ Application.id }}">
                        <input type="submit" value="Reject" name="status">
                    </center></td> 
                     </tr>

                    {% empty %}
                     <p>No application for this job yet...</p>
                    {% endfor %}

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
    </div>`
```

Here is my view file

```
`def JobDashboard(request, jobs_id):
    Job = get_object_or_404(job, pk= jobs_id, created_by = request.user)
    print(request.method)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        query= Application.objects.get(id=request.POST.get("Application_id"))
        
        if request.POST.get("status"):
            status = request.POST.get('status')
            print(status)
            query.save()


    return render(request, "View_Dashboard_job.html", {"Job":Job})`
```

In print status it gives whatever I clicked but not pushing to the database

[FrontEnd View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blXHV.png)

Comment: i guess you cannot have more than 1 submit button on a single form. you can have a radio button select "shortlist" or "reject" status. then a single submit button for the form to submit data. and send that status radio button value in the request.

Comment: @MuhammadWaqarAnwar Its not submit button its just status change button

Comment: its type is of submit button that is what i am trying to say that you cannot have more than 1 submit button on a form i guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are wanting update the query object's status field with the submitted value for status, you have missed out the object in your code...

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        query= Application.objects.get(id=request.POST.get("Application_id"))
        
        if request.POST.get("status"):
            #Don't forget to use query.status rather than just status
            query.status = request.POST.get('status')
            print(status)
            query.save()
```